# How to save zip file into Blob field with Oracle Sql Developer

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using Oracle SQL Developer on MacOS and I am trying to save zip file into Blob field. I know how to load any other file type by clicking "Load" button and then selecting the file.

[image]

The problem is that when I select the zip file and click on Open, it does not select that file, but shows the me the content of zip file and then I can select only one file from that zip. This is not what I want, because I want to upload the whole zip.

Is there any setting in Oracle SQL Developer or any other way?

I do not have such problem on same table when using PLSQL Developer on Windows machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found out that when I have a zip file in a folder, then Oracle Sql Developer automatically shows also folders for this file, even if does not exist in reality on disk. The name of the folder and the file is the same including extension. Different is only the icon. If you select archive then loading to blob works ok. This is the behaviour on MacOS. I did not test it on other systems. On bottom picture is the example of folder containing only 2 zip files and how it looks when you try selecting file from that folder.

[image]

Comment: Nice! I totally overlooked this. Thanks for figuring this out and sharing.